# Component Exception: View config getter callback for component must be a function (received 'undefined')

Tags: react-native, function, components

Im doing basic react native navigation example, but im getting error when i try to make it work!

Here is the navigation module:

```
// In App.js in a new project

import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { LoginScreen } from "./Components/Login/LoginScreen.js";
import "./Components/Main/MainScreen.js";


const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={"LoginScreen"} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={"MainScreen"} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the LoginScreen.js:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The error that i get is: Component Exception: View config getter callback for component 'LoginScreen' must be a function (received 'undefined')

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** Remove the quotes when passing in a component to the `component` prop of a screen.

---

The documentation specifies the `component` prop as follows:

> The React Component to render for the screen

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#component

So it doesn't work because you're passing in a `string` instead of a react component.

---

Instead of this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={"LoginScreen"} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={"MainScreen"} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

do this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```